# Repetir n veces registros

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Hola buenas tardes a todos,

Tengo un archivo Excel que importo a SqlServer mediante un Windows Forms C#.
Por cada registro importado lo muestro en un DGV y quiero repetirlo n cantidad de veces, pero solo me esta repitiendo el primer registro del DGV.

Para ello tengo los siguientes ciclos while para repetir las n veces y foreach para recorrer el DGV.

Cual puede ser el problema que tengo este es el código:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x=0;
        if ((DGVFile.Rows.Count > 0))
        {
            cnx.Open();
            try
            {
                SqlTransaction transaction;
                transaction = cnx.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ExternalData (LCode,text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,idApplication) values (@DATA_Cod, @DATA_text1, @DATA_text2, @DATA_text3, @DATA_text4, @DATA_text5, @DATA_idapp)", cnx);

                    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_Cod", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_text1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_text2", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_text3", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_text4", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_text5", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA_idapp", SqlDbType.Int);


                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVFile.Rows)
                    {
                        while (x <5 )
                        {
                            
                                cmd.Parameters["@DATA_Cod"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["LCode"].Value);
                                cmd.Parameters["@DATA_text1"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text1"].Value);
                                cmd.Parameters["@DATA_text2"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text2"].Value);
                                cmd.Parameters["@DATA_text3"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text3"].Value);
                                cmd.Parameters["@DATA_text4"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text4"].Value);
                                cmd.Parameters["@DATA_text5"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["text5"].Value);
                                cmd.Parameters["@DATA_idapp"].Value = cmbSelectApp.SelectedValue;
                                x += 1;
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                cnx.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Records has been saved!", "Succed!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not exists data", "Missing Data",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Saludos

DS

Comment: Tu problema es que no re-inicias el valor de `x`, entonces para todas las filas después de la primera no se cumple la condición del `while (x<5)`. Cambia la inicialización de la variable para que esté dentro del `foreach`, justo antes del `while`.

Comment: @jachguate
Tienes razón con ese cambio me ha funcionado.
Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda, lo publiqué como respuesta con algunos comentarios adicionales. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que no re-inicias el valor de la variable `x` en un lugar apropiado, entonces, para todas las filas después de la primera, no se cumple la condición del `while (x<5)`.

La solución es cambiar de lugar la inicialización de la variable para que esté dentro del `foreach`, justo antes del `while`, de manera que para cada fila nueva, valga cero y el `while` se repita las veces que quires:

```
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVFile.Rows)
                {
                    //mueve la declaración e inicialización de la variable aquí
                    int x=0;
                    while (x <5 )
                    {
```

Para finalizar, solo comentar que, si utilizaras un ciclo `for` esto no hubiera pasado. En general, cuando quiero que un ciclo se ejecute un número pre-determinado de veces, utilizo un ciclo `for`. No solo es la elección más natural, sino que, al leer el código, queda claro desde el inicio que la intención es que se ejecute cierto número de veces y, de paso, se evitan *bugs* como el que tenía tu código:

```
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGVFile.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
                    {
```